# Asp.Net Core "Web API" Routes Returning 404 Not Found

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

On Windows 7 Dev machines that have Asp.net Core 2, all our API specific routes that return data (not Views) work.

A developer recently got the API setup on his new Windows 10 machine.   When we run the routes in Postman or swagger, he can only get one particular `GET` route to work (extra tidbit - so happens this is the only route that does not call `EntityFramework`).

All other routes return a `404 Not Found` as if the URLs don’t exist. It’s not our code returning the `404`, it’s the platform itself.

None of our code is being executed since the 404 is being returned by the server, so no useful logging either.

I also deployed and tested it on a Win server 2016 machine, and getting the same exact issue.

The last thing I did on this server was install the Asp.net Core 2 SDK but had no effect.

some code:

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/v1/Signatures/Request")]
public class SignatureRequestController : ControllerBase

[HttpPost]
[Route("")]
public async Task<SignatureRequestBaseResponse> 
CreateSignatureRequestAsync([FromBody]SignatureRequest signatureRequest)
```

example POST url:

```
http://localhost/My.API/api/v1/signatures/request/
```

example json body:

```
{
    "clientApplicationInstanceId" : "4318704B-7F90-4CAE-87A9-842F2925FE45",
    "facilityId" : "PT",
    "contact": "me@my.com",
    "documentInstanceGuid" : "cc46c96f-cd78-448e-a376-cb4220d49a52",
    "messageType" : "1",
    "localeId": 1,
    "field": 
                {
                    "fieldId": 45,
                    "signatureType": "4",
                    "displayName": "Short Display Name from iMed4Web",
                    "signerNameCaption": "signer name caption",
                    "signerAddressCaption": "address caption",
                    "signerCityStateZipCaption": "city state zip caption"
                },
    "documentPreviewHtml": "too long to show..."
}
```

Comment: Post the rest of your routing configuration (`Startup.cs` and the attribute routes in this controller). In routing **the first match wins**, so it is likely there is another route that is matching that you didn't intend to.

Comment: Turned out to be something with Serilog.  But only on Windows Server 2016.  Sigh.

Answer (score 4):

You should apply Route attribute to controller methods (actions), and you can also point the http verb associated with the routes.
Take a look at t[his documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing#attribute-routing), it will help you.

Comment: @TheDudeAbides are you using default routes, and only route attributes? Is the any mapRoutes in your startup class?

Comment: using all attribute routes for api.   There is the default home controller one for the view.  We deleted the HomeController and View.  I could probably remove that route now and see

Comment: I think that must have to be the route matching. Can you paste here a snippet of your Startup class where you do, and if you do, some route mapping?
When a request arrives, the route collection is processed in order, the order matters here.

Answer (score 3):

This happened to me with the newest Core 3.1 Asp.Net Core Web App template. The issue was that the default wireup was this:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
    endpoints.MapControllers();
});
```

But, it needed to be this:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
    endpoints.MapControllers();
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
    );
});
```

The previous answer lead me to the solution, but I wanted to post a more explicit answer in case it was helpful to others.